# Hide/show buttons based on select value in form

Tags: angular

I am trying to hide/show buttons based on a value that is selected in a dropdown menu. My current implementation is not working as expected.

Here is my code

```
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12">
    <div class="ui-g-6 ui-sm-12">
      <div class="input-container">
        <label for="identityTypeId">Identity document type*</label>
        <p-dropdown [options]="identityDocTypeArr" formControlName="identityTypeId" id="identityTypeId" placeholder="Select"></p-dropdown>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-6 ui-sm-12">
      <div class="input-container">
        <label for="identityValue">Identity number*</label>
        <input id="identityValue" type="text" formControlName="identityValue" size="50" placeholder="0000000000000" (blur)="validateSouthAfricanID()">
        <span *ngIf="offerFormGroup.controls.identityValue.status == 'VALID' && offerFormGroup.controls.identityValue.touched && idVal != false">
          <img class="valid-input-icon" src="../../../../../assets/icons/checkedGreen.png">
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12 " *ngIf="iddoctype == 4">
  <div class="ui-g-12 ui-sm-12">
    <div class="ui-g-9"></div>
    <div class="ui-g-3 button-holder" style="text-align:right;">
      <button
        [disabled]="!offerFormGroup.valid || idVal == false"
        type="button"
        class="main create"
        (click)="createCandidate(false)">
        CREATE CANDIDATE
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12 " *ngIf="iddoctype != 4">
  <div class="ui-g-12 ui-sm-12">
    <div class="ui-g-9"></div>
    <div class="ui-g-3 button-holder" style="text-align:right;">
      <button
        [disabled]="!offerFormGroup.valid"
        type="button"
        class="main create"
        (click)="createCandidate(false)">
        CREATE CANDIDATE
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  validateInputs() {
      const iddoctype = this.offerFormGroup.get('identityTypeId').value;
      if (iddoctype == 4) {
        if (this.idVal == false) {
          this._errorService.openErrorPopup('Please enter valid identity number.');
          return false;
        } else {
        }
      }
      return true;
  }
```

So basically if iddoctype = 4 then show one button and hide another and viva versa. Please assist.

Comment: How do you set that `iddoctype`?

Comment: Can you just setup an onclick on the your dropdown to call a javascript function that checks if it is a certain value then if trueit  hide the button by added a style="display:none;"

Comment: I can't see where you're binding a value to iddoctype. There doesn't seem to be a binding on the selected value of the drop down? Something like [selected]="iddoctype".

Comment: I have added how I set the iddoctype value

Comment: I don't see where `validateInputs` is executed. Nevertheless you don't update the component property, but just create new constant inside `validateInputs` method. Quick (but not the best) solution is to replace `iddoctype != 4` inside `*ngIf` with `offerFormGroup.get('identityTypeId').value != 4` (same for ` == 4`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html just add the following `*ngIf` conditions

```
<button *ngIf="this.offerFormGroup.get('identityTypeId').value === 4">
    Show when iddoctype is 4
</button>
<button *ngIf="this.offerFormGroup.get('identityTypeId').value !== 4">
    Show when iddoctype is not 4
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `offerFormGroup.get('identityTypeId').value` inside template will work, but the code is executed during every change detection cycle. Here it's not a big deal, but when you have more complex logic it may be an issue.

Another approach is to be more reactive.

Inside component code add:

```js
identityTypeId$ = this.offerFormGroup.get('identityTypeId').valueChanges
// or
showSomeButton$ = this.offerFormGroup.get('identityTypeId').valueChanges.pipe(map(value => value == 4))
```

Then inside template

```html
<div *ngIf="(identityTypeId$ | async) == 4">
```